# Linked List in C error -- Invalid Initalizer error

Tags: c, list, struct, initializer

I am attempting to create a Linked List using C (NOT C++). The Linked List is initialized through the function llinit() which should return a list struct. However, when I compile the code I get an error stating "error: invalid initializer" in the lltester.c file. Why is this?

This is the function used to initialize the linked list in my llist.c file:

```
list llinit()
{
    list* ll = malloc(sizeof(list));
    ll->head = NULL;
    ll->tail = NULL;
    return *ll;
}
```

This is the list struct in my llist.h file:

```
typedef struct {
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} list;
```

This is my main function in my lltester.c file where I attempt to initialize the list:

```
int main()
{
    list myList= llinit(); //This is the line where the error occurs on!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You `llinit` function does an unnecessary heap allocation and leaks the pointer.

Comment: @Medinoc, Unless he suddenly introduces data into `struct list`.

Comment: @Medinoc, how can I create the list struct without leaking the pointer?

Comment: By either returning the pointer (if you want your list structure to be on the heap) or simply by not using `malloc` and just declaring your `list` as a local variable (since you return it by value).

Comment: By declaring the list as a local variable I assume you mean: `list ll;` and then I would just have `return ll;`?

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE (sscce.org) ... otherwise we're stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Do you even include llist.h into lltester.c? Why do people come here expecting help but act so unhelpfully themselves?

Comment: What is `myList.llPushBack`? What language are you writing in? C does not have member functions.

Comment: Yes, I do include llist.h into lltester.c And yes, it is C. I realize the member function was bad code. I've eliminated that in the main() since it is not part of the problem.

Comment: Still no SSCCE. Voting to close.

Comment: WOW... well, I found my mistake in the header file. I had accidentally named the declaration llInit instead of llinit... Next time I'll post a SSCCE, I'm sure you would've noticed my mistake right away @Jim Balter

Comment: Yes, someone here certainly would have noticed that. Good lesson and thanks for taking it to heart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is leaking memory, since it's allocating the list with `malloc()` then returning that structure's content *by value*.

if you want to have a function that returns an empty list by value, you should do just that:

```
list llinit()
{
    list ll;
    ll.head = NULL;
    ll.tail = NULL;

    return ll;
}
```

The above is just fine, there's no risk of the value "disappearing" due to it going out of scope, this is just as safe as e.g. a function returning a local `int` value. The return *value* (all of it!) is copied to the caller's memory as needed.

It's then trivial for the *caller* to decide whether or not the node should be on the heap or not.

**UPDATE**: [Here is the code on ideone](http://ideone.com/KmFu31), it really does compile and does not generate an error for the assignment in `main()`.

Comment: This is exactly what I have now, and it still throws the same error stating: "error: invalid initalizer". This error is on the same line of code as stated above.

Comment: @BenBeck No one can help you because you haven't posted a complete program and you haven't mentioned your compiler and options.

Comment: As an added advantage to that solution, there is no dynamic memory allocation involved here, meaning no error checking to be done and no error code to return from the caller.

Comment: @BenBeck I'm sorry, I don't quite believe you. I added a link to ideone, see for youself. It compiles.

Comment: @BenBeck which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Medinoc I have solved this problem, it was a very simple yet not easily noticeable mistake. It couldn't have been resolved on here sincce I did not post the entirety of my code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare the structure as

```
typedef struct _list{
list* head;  /* could have been struct node* as well */
list* tail;
```

} list;

Also the list is your custom struture. And the llPushBack() is not a bember of your structure.

Comment: I don't think this will work. The typedef doesn't take effect until the semicolon, so `list` is an undefined type. OP must have `node` defined elsewhere.

Comment: Plus, your answer assumes that a list node is a list, which is exactly how *not* to do a linked list in my book. It causes confusion.

Comment: The correct way to to define self-referencing struct types is `typedef struct list list; struct list { ...};`